# Database connection required for MFC smartcard application using VC++

Tags: database, visual-c++, windows-ce

We are going to develop smart device application in windows ce using MFC smart card device project type using VC++.So any one provide detail tutorial or links to setup project to connect with database and which database we have to use with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the MFC Database classes
CRecordset is able to print a database table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/92bcy0kw.aspx

CDatabase is required for directly connecting to your database. Look up the msdn or search for "MFC ODBC Application" or "CRecordset MFC tutorial"

Comment: can you please help how to setup project in visual studio i mean which library is required to add or any special setting to programming environment ?

Comment: Please set up a normal visual studio project. don't check the options for the database support. when your project is created, open the class wizard and on the right side, you open the dropdown. Select the option "ODBC-Consumer". After that, you can chose your ODBC Setup. iIf you don't know what this is, watch this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3GZidOwGmM